# Using Open.Window in Chrome to create a new Pinned Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know you cannot use `chrome.tabs.create` in a content script.

I want to create bookmarks that open in a pinned tab without having an make an extension.

I tried to pass it like a custom spec
`Window.Open ("", "", "pinned=true")`  It opens it like a webapp with a reduced sized title bar and no tabs.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: unless there's already a tab with the name you're passing into window.open, it will automatically open in a new window.

Comment: Are you saying if I pass the pinned attribute but in an already open tab, it will pin?